# What would be the most convenient way to check that a string begins with another one?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to have a proper way to check whether a string is the beginning of another string (and that they are not the same).

Given `s1` and `s2` I have the following possibilities:

```
LENGTH(s1) < LENGTH(s2) AND SUBSTR(s2, 1, LENGTH(s1)) = s1

s2 LIKE replace(replace(replace(s1,'\','\\'),'%','\%'),'_','\_') || '_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Is there a better way with native functions I don't know of?

**Note: `s1` and `s2` might contain `%`, `_` or any other characters!**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a better way, but for completeness there is also:

```
LENGTH(s1) < LENGTH(s2) AND INSTR(s2,s1) = 1
```

Comment: Not *quite* the same - these conditions test whether s1 is contained within s2, not whether s2 *starts* with s1.

Comment: This would work if you specified the optional POSITION parameter for `INSTR()` i.e. `INSTR(s2,s1, 1) = 1`

Comment: I don't agree (or am losing my marbles): INSTR(s2,s1) returns the *position* of the *first* occurence of s1 in s2.  If it returns 1, that means s2 starts with s1.  If not please explain why not!

Comment: @APC: [The default for `POSITION` is 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm)

Comment: Good, my marbles *are* intact then!

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple if statement should do it:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  s1 varchar2(1000) := 'hellothere';
  s2 varchar2(1000) := 'hello';
begin
  if s1 != s2 and s1 like s2||'%' then
    dbms_output.put_line('There are alike');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('not alike');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Same remark as for @Mark Bannister: does not handle the case where `s1` and `s2` have special characters.